# How to convert a value retrieved from AWS to a string

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-go

We are using version 2 of the AWS SDK for Go to retrieve data in tables from DynamoDB.
Since some of the DynamoDB contains duplicate data, we have created a function to remove duplicates.

```golang
func include(slice []string, item string) bool {
    for _, user := range slice {
        if user == item {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Data retrieval from DynamoDB is performed by this code.

```golang
op, err := client.Scan(ctx, &dynamodb.ScanInput{
        TableName: aws.String(table),
    })
```

I want to take an element from op and convert it to a string for comparison, but I don't know how to convert it to a string.

Can you convert from AWS type to string? If so, please let me know how to write it.

Comment: What exactly is `op`?

Comment: `aws.StringValue` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `strconv` package to convert the data to a string:

```
import "strconv"

// ...

op, err := client.Scan(ctx, &dynamodb.ScanInput{
        TableName: aws.String(table),
    })

var results []string

for _, item := range op.Items {
    // convert each item in op.Items to a string
    resultString := strconv.Itoa(int(item))
    if !include(results, resultString) {
        results = append(results, resultString)
    }
}
```

Also, the specific conversion method may depend on the data type of the item in `op.Items`. That is why you might need to use the `fmt.Sprintf()` function instead of the `strconv` package.